При клике на другие Элементы нужно переключать Активный класс
При клике на Список менять активный класс у span. Изначально есть активный span, при клике на другой, основной удаляется и на новый добавляется класс итд.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
  <style> .active-list{
    color: red;
    }</style>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class='span active-list'>Первый</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class='span'>Второй</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class='span'>Третий</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class='span'>Итд</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>

const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span')

spans.forEach(item => item...)




const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.span');

for (let span of spans) {
  span.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const activeSpan = document.querySelector('.span.active-list');
    activeSpan.classList.remove('active-list');
    span.classList.add('active-list');
  })
}
.active-list {
  color: red;
}
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class='span active-list'>Первый</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class='span'>Второй</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class='span'>Третий</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class='span'>Итд</span>
  </li>
</ul>




Работает, спасибо. Делал через forEach, но не работало.
